# Capturing javascript updates with selenium

Tags: selenium

I'd like to extract a stream of data from a live webpage updated continuously by a javascript code that doesn't reload the page itself. How do I do this with selenium if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a new/added element in a loop. It could look like this in Java:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("theId"));
int count = 0;

while (element != null && count < 60) {

    // get the element again
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("theId"));

    // do something with the element...
    log(element.text());

    // wait one second
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    // increment a count if you want to eventually escape this loop, in case you never find your elment
    count++;
}
```

If that doesn't work for your purpose, you can get the full source code of the page and parse it for whatever information you are looking for.

```
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
```

You can do that in a loop like above, and keep trying until you reach a timeout or find the updated info.

Comment: If this answer doesn't help, can you provide more detail? Maybe you can show the JavaScript code which does the updating, or the part of the page code that gets updated?